# Can Any one tells me how to do these mentions below in laravel : - value="{{ $client->street_address?old('street_address') }}"

Tags: php, laravel, return-value, laravel-blade

This is my `value="{{ $client->street_address}}"` and this is my old value `{{ old('street_address') }}`.

I want to merge a laravel session like this `value="{{ $client->street_address ? old('street_address') }}"`. Basically laravel stores session and input value in session, so I want to display previous input with value coming from database.

If a condition is not satisfied it will return to same page with old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy, you want to show `old` value if there is any, but if there is no `old` value, then show database value.

If you check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old), you will see you can pass a second argument to `old` and it will use it as a default value when `old` does not have a value to show, so you avoid doing an `if` check or anything similar.

Your Blade should be like this:

```html
{{ old('street_address', $client->street_address) }}
```

Comment: @RonnyDsouza Can you mark this answer as correct, please ?

Comment: off course man i confirm your answer.